# Ubuntu focal fossa python3 error - Does this error happen to everyone?

Tags: apt, 20.04, python3, pip, error-handling

Does this error happen to everyone?

1. Install Ubuntu Focal Fossa.
2. Then install the python3-pip
   (At this stage, Python3 is installed automatically)

   ```
   Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)
   [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   ```
3. After you have created the username and made the settings:

   ```
   sudo python3
   >>> help()
   help> modules
   ```

Now at this stage you will encounter an error message.

```
Error: Could not import kivy. Please install it using the instructions mentioned here `https://kivy.org/#download` .
```

**The point is that this error will not occur if done without sudo.**

```
python3
>>> help()
help> modules
```

Comment: Why would you need sudo to run python?

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg -l | grep -i kivy`, `sudo find / -name "Kivy*-info" 2> /dev/null` to the question by editing it.

Comment: @N0rbert The former had no output and the latter  'hang' the terminal.In my opinion, the problem is caused by focal fossa's default python. ```Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)```.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi Most Python programs do not install without sudo. However, there is no installation problem so far.

Comment: Please wait for complete output of last command `sudo find / -name "Kivy*-info" 2> /dev/null` and share its output. I do not see any issues on fresh 20.04 LTS VM, you are doing something wrong, or do not tell us all the truth.

Comment: *Most Python programs do not install without sudo* -- What are you trying to do? You might need sudo to install a package systemwide using `pip`, but I did not get why or how you would install a program from the python shell itself. Also, did you install `python3-kivy` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Error: Could not import kivy. Please install it using the instructions mentioned here https://kivy.org/#download` error message that you got is reproducible in Ubuntu under the same circumstances. The `modules` python3 instruction takes a while to run and generates a lot of results that may include information about files that were installed by a non-root user, therefore for security reason you should not run this instruction in a root python3 shell. The `python3` command is normally run by a normal user, and you should not run python3 as root.